# PowerShell: List all items except for certain files

Tags: powershell

```
Get-childItem | Where-Object { ($_.CreationTime).ToString('dd/MM/yyyy') -EQ 01/01/2017}
```

How do you create exceptions when listing files ? So if I want to list every file in a directory apart from files called "`File 1`" and "`File 2`"

Answer (score 2):

Using the `-Exclude` parameter on `Get-ChildItem`:

```
Get-ChildItem -Exclude File1,File2 | Where-Object { ($_.CreationTime).ToString('dd/MM/yyyy') -EQ 01/01/2017}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-childItem | Where-Object {$_.Name -ne 'file 1' -and $_.name -ne 'file 2'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either of the above examples will work, it's more of a preference. I personally like to do as much filtering of the data before I pass it along the pipeline.